# Remote backup of Raspberry Pi sd card from Windows

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi

This references details a procedure for backing up the SD card on a running Raspberry Pi from and to a file on another computer (https://johnatilano.com/2016/11/25/use-ssh-and-dd-to-remotely-backup-a-raspberry-pi/)

To do this from a Windows PC it is necessary to install a new "DD tool" for Windows, also referenced above.  I've done all of this and thought I had the process figured out, the following command run from a Windows CMD window does create a file on my Windows PC, but shows an error message which I can not figure out.

```
c:\Windows\System32>ssh me@192.168.xxx.yyy “sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M | gzip -” | dd of=\\.\c:/Users/me/Desktop/rPi_backup.gz –progress
```

I have run this on my LAN to two different Pi's (3B and 4B), Here is the output from the later after about 30 minutes:

> c:\Windows\System32>ssh me@192.168.xxx.yyy “sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0
> bs=1M | gzip -” | dd of=\.\c:/Users/me/Desktop/rPi_backup.gz
> –progress
>
> rawwrite dd for windows version 0.5. Written by John Newbigin This
> program is covered by the GPL. See copying.txt for details
> 0me@192.168.xxx.yyy‘s password:
>
> 11,754,655,23215193+1 records in 15193+1 records out 15931539456 bytes
> (16 GB, 15 GiB) copied, 2528.86 s, 6.3 MB/s 11,755,209,216Error
> reading file: 109 The pipe has been ended
>
> 22959393+0 records in 22959393+0 records out

I got the same Error 109 for both Pi's.  I have checked the SD cards and they are functional, not corrupted nor have any "dirty bits".  I have tried to find the error code description, but nothing I see seems to apply to this situation.

Can anyone help me with this problem.  I posted it to the above reference, but have not gotten any meaningful replies....RDK

EDIT after using Maxim Sagaydachny's suggestion (in comments).  It worked and I got a .gz file on my desktop.  I used BalenaEtcher to expand and copy it to an SD card, same size as that of the source.  The Pi booted up but it appears that the restored version is a bit crippled, the Pi boots ok, I can log on (console and SSH) but I get this message just after I log on:

> -bash: /etc/profile.d/magnum_path.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token
> `$'sʧ\237\376\351\370'' -bash: /etc/profile.d/magnum_path.sh: line 1:` MA▒$▒g▒p▒[▒kh▒▒▒▒▒D(sʧ▒▒▒▒|▒Kq/t
> ▒▒▒ ▒9▒$A▒6▒▒f▒▒V▒▒▒Y▒▒     UX▒O:▒▒35▒▒1z▒׎▒YC#▒ȓ!▒ӪW▒▒GM▒
> <▒▒'▒▒▒`W=|k▒▒▒V ▒9▒▒R▒[j▒
> *▒▒ֈ▒▒

I also noted a message in the bootup screen but it went by too fast to fully read so the following i s a stab at what it really said.  Something about the expected number of ?? was, for example, 273 and it only sees 272. And I think it was referencing mmcblk0p2....RDK

Comment: why do you need to pass data through ```dd``` at windows side? why not redirect output into file directly? i.e. ```ssh me@192.168.xxx.yyy “sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M | gzip -” > c:/Users/me/Desktop/rPi_backup.gz```

Comment: Thanks for the reply/comment.  I will give this a try and let you know.

Comment: If have edited my question with details of the results of Maxim's suggestion

Comment: this kind of backup does not make any sense to me for two reasons: 1) you have no guarantee that you get proper copy of partition because it is mounted in read-write mode and files are getting changed on it during copy - you get dirty copy of file system with unpredictable behavior once such backup is restored; 2) you do not need to copy system files or any trash of unused sectors. You could probably improve your chances by using ```sync``` prior ```dd``` and configuring filesystem to postponing cache writes but you will still end-up with snapshot having non-closed files which is bad.

Comment: Good analysis, thanks.  I'm interested in this idea/technique as I have several Pi's at remote locations and this seemed like a good way to periodically back up the SD card.  Thanks again, I look for something else....